# FileInfo.Length is greater than 0 but File is Empty?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have an application that crunches a bunch of text files. Currently, I have code like this (snipped-together excerpt):

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(...)
if (info.Length > 0) {
    string content = getFileContents(...);
        // uses a StreamReader
        // returns reader.ReadToEnd();
    Debug.Assert(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contents)); // FAIL
}

private string getFileContents(string filename)
    {
        TextReader reader = null;
        string text = "";

        try
        {
            reader = new StreamReader(filename);
            text = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // File is concurrently accessed. Come back later.
            text = "";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }
        }

        return text;
    }
```

Why am I getting a failed assert? The FileInfo.Length attribute was already used to validate that the file is non-empty.

**Edit:** This appears to be a bug -- I'm catching IO exceptions and returning empty-string. But, because of the discussion around fileInfo.Length(), here's something interesting: fileInfo.Length returns 2 for an empty, only-BOM-marker text file (created in Notepad).

Comment: Perhaps the file only contains a BOM? But the problem is probably within the getFileContents function you didn't post. A race condition is also possible in theory, but unlikely in practice. What is the content of the file where it fails?

Comment: I'll check. It happened a couple of times so I assumed it's a bug. It's not likely to be a race condition, since the file-input code is single-threaded and I'm not editing files on that drive at the moment. I also catch IO exceptions on file-open and skip the file.

Comment: Also, BOM returns a non-zero length, but ReadToEnd() gives us an empty string; see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See that `catch (IOException)` block you have?  That's what returns an empty string and triggers the assert even when the file is not empty.

Comment: Bingo. Complete oversight on my end.

Answer (score 5):

You might have a file which is empty apart from a byte-order mark. I *think* `TextReader.ReadToEnd()` would remove the byte-order mark, giving you an empty string.

Alternatively, the file could have been truncated between checking the length and reading it.

For diagnostic purposes, I suggest you log the file length when you get an empty string.

Comment: You're correct on that italicised thinking. Unless you explicitly open it as a BOMless encoding like US-ASCII, it'll eat the BOM (as indeed, it should).

Comment: A file with just BOM returns a non-zero length, but ReadToEnd() gives empty contents; see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember well, a file ends with end of file, which won't be included when you call ReadToEnd.

Therefore, the file size is not 0, but it's content size is.

Comment: Nope, EOF is only handled by the console, but not by the `StreamReader`. See my quick test: http://pastebin.com/mhjr8yrV

Comment: Yes, but, but we are speaking about FileInfo.Length, which is the complete File length, not the stream reader length. I am quite sure that they are not equal (which this question seems to demonstrate)

Comment: @Lucero I don't really understand your pastebin example.

Comment: @ashes999, the point is that the EOF character 26 is read into the string normally, it does not stop nor break there, so that a possible EOF character is not the cause for the problem at hand.

Comment: I agree with you Lucero, the root cause here is thinking that FileInfo.Length == FileStream.Length == string.Length .

Answer (score 0):

What's in the `getFileContents` method?

It may be repositioning the stream's pointer to the end of the stream before ReadToEnd() is called.